# Apache doesn't download files stored outside of default web folder

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos

I've got a webserver from Vultr running on CentOS Stream 9. The files I want people to be able to download are stored on a separate hard drive mounted to /mnt/box/public/. I've set Apache to host it as a file index. Apache won't allow downloading the files, but instead displays them as text. This isn't a problem if the files are stored in Apache's web folder `/var/www/` but I want the files to be on the other drive.

I'm quite new to Linux stuff. I tried disabling SELinux and following [this](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/) guide, but neither fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I edited your question for clarity and readability. Please check, and correct any possible errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Trying to have Apache use utf-8 (to display **ö** and **ä** specifically) I had set `ForceType text/html; charset=utf-8` in `httpd.conf` which did display the filenames in utf-8 but also made the files display as text.

After this I needed to figure out how to use utf-8 as `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` didn't work. `IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8` fixed that problem

Comment: Nice :-) Please don't forget to check back tomorrow to accept your answer. This will remove the question from Unanswered -queue and help others with similar problem identify this as resolved.

Comment: Oops! I edited your question for clarity, adding code brackets etc. Please check the edit and correct any mistakes.

Comment: all seems fine :)